# Send or Copy file by workflow which is editing in SharePoint

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

If in SharePoint is some way to send or copy file which is editing? In Windows even file is editing I can copy and paste copy of file but when I try to do it in SharePoint by workflow I get error and workflow crash with error "file is lock to editing e.t.c."

I tried many way and workflow actions even custom but all finished the same error...

Could anyone help my?

I use SharePoint Foundation.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can try the action in an eventhandler/custom webpart using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivilages.

Comment: But How I can do it? Thanks for your support